# 505 Error Heroku Deploying Personal Website

Tags: php, heroku, web-deployment

I'm trying to host my personal website on heroku. My website only has html, css, and javascript files, and I read that heroku only deploys apps written in ruby, node, scala, php, etc. So, I followed this tutorial (http://www.lemiffe.com/how-to-deploy-a-static-page-to-heroku-the-easy-way/) and changed my `index.html` file to `home.html` and included an `index.php` file that has the following code: `<?php include_once("home.html"); ?>`.

I've successfully pushed it to heroku, but when I open the heroku url of my app, it gives me a 505 error.

Below is my `heroku log`:

```
2015-11-14T02:42:05.497208+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 63ae6bd by email@gmail.com
2015-11-14T02:42:05.497305+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by email@gmail.com
2015-11-14T02:42:05.651545+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-14T02:42:05.651555+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-11-14T02:42:05.820048+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-11-14T02:42:08.998026+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-11-14T02:42:09.746422+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2`
2015-11-14T02:42:09.909064+00:00 app[web.1]: Going down, terminating child processes...
2015-11-14T02:42:10.844965+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2015-11-14T02:42:12.439647+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting php-fpm...
2015-11-14T02:42:12.243079+00:00 app[web.1]: Optimizing defaults for 1X dyno...
2015-11-14T02:42:12.435588+00:00 app[web.1]: 4 processes at 128MB memory limit.
2015-11-14T02:42:14.442033+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting httpd...
2015-11-14T02:42:14.672772+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-11-14T02:44:38.663711+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mywebsite.herokuapp.com request_id=45aae2bd-a6f8-4023-86cf-6aedd5d23882 fwd="138.110.234.184" dyno=web.1 connect=12ms service=2ms status=500 bytes=224
2015-11-14T02:44:38.663113+00:00 app[web.1]: [14-Nov-2015 02:44:38 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in /app/index.php on line 1
2015-11-14T02:44:38.663580+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.146.233.83 - - [14/Nov/2015:02:44:38 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said 505 error (505 is really quite an exotic error!) but it is actually just a 500 error according to the log you pasted.  500 is the typical server side error, in this case:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in /app/index.php on line 1

I'd bet your php file has a space in it or something that isn't quite right.  Make sure it looks like what you pasted as instructed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17531897/237091

Comment: My braces were wrong. I had "<?php include_once("home.html"); ?<" instead of "<?php include_once("home.html"); ?>". Thank you!

Comment: @johnwj *"and included an index.php file that has the following code: `<?php include_once("home.html"); ?>`"* - What you posted, doesn't support the question and what you were really using. `<?php include_once("home.html"); ?<`

Answer (score 0):

Well , whenever your Web-page's contain HTML, CSS and JavaScript , so follow just 2 steps :

1) Make one file give name as index.html (keep evreything in it) ex:script,stylesheet & body.

2) Now, change these file, **copy and paste these same file** but change domain to **index.php**

Then deploy on a Heroku.

Hence this method will help you to deploy your Web-Pages