# Static Website Links Does not work on Heroku

Tags: html, css, rack

I deploy a static website on heroku using RACK (https://sixth-group.herokuapp.com/).
it works good.
But when i click on the links it does not work and the other pages does not appear?
anyone help please!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to upload a simple html and javascript file structure to heroku?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551273/is-it-possible-to-upload-a-simple-html-and-javascript-file-structure-to-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me perfectly on Heroku.

**Html:**

```
<a href="/contact.html"> Contact Us </a>
```

**Config.ru**

```
use Rack::Static,
  :urls => ["/images", "/js", "/css"],
  :root => "public"

static_page_mappings = {
  '/'             => 'public/index.html',
  '/contact.html' => 'public/contact.html'
}

static_page_mappings.each do |req, file|
  map req do 
    run Proc.new { |env|
      [
        200, 
        {
          'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
          'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=6400',
        },
        File.open(file, File::RDONLY)
      ]
    }
  end
end
```